# Can The Style of A Table In Numbers Be Set Programmatically

Tags: applescript

Pretty straight forward. There are different styles of tables to choose from manually. The AppleScript Numbers library doesn't mention the style can be set, and an internet search isn't turning up many results. Has anyone had success or made the ultimate decision that it can't be done? I'm hoping it can be done without using system events to "click" a table style.

```
        set newTable to make new table with properties {style:"Something here?", column count:10, header column count:1, footer row count:1, position:{0, 72}, name:"Sample Table", header row count:1, row count:10}
        #Or Here?
        tell newtable
        set style of table somehow?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically yes. You could set the properties of rows and columns in the `tell newTable` area. Although it's not the *easy* way, it can still be done if you build it from scratch. (Which you are doing)

**EDIT** To clarify with a little more and include examples, if you're having trouble identifying additional properties that can be set, you could use `get properties of table 1` to guide you further if the library isn't much assistance. Getting properties would yield you results similar to below.

```
tell application "Numbers"
get properties of table 1 of sheet 1 of document 1

(* returned from get properties of table
{locked:false, cell range:range "A1:E10" of table 1 of sheet 1 of document id "4F9B1A5C-CC34-4C74-B05C-4856839EE760" of application "Numbers", column count:5, parent:sheet 1 of document id "4F9B1A5C-CC34-4C74-B05C-4856839EE760" of application "Numbers", header column count:1, footer row count:0, class:table, header columns frozen:true, position:{16, 43}, filtered:false, header rows frozen:true, width:490, name:"Table 1", selection range:range "A1:E10" of table 1 of sheet 1 of document id "4F9B1A5C-CC34-4C74-B05C-4856839EE760" of application "Numbers", header row count:1, height:203, row count:10}
*)

get properties of row 1 of table 1 of sheet 1 of document 1

(* returned from get properties of row
{vertical alignment:top, font name:"Helvetica-Bold", class:row, background color:{18205, 30509, 7341}, name:"1", text wrap:true, text color:{65528, 65533, 65524}, alignment:auto align, format:automatic, address:1, font size:10.0, height:20.625}
*)

get properties of column 1 of table 1 of sheet 1 of document 1

(*returned from get properties of column
{vertical alignment:top, font name:"Helvetica-Bold", class:column, background color:{27817, 27821, 27814}, width:98.0, format:automatic, text wrap:true, text color:{65528, 65533, 65524}, alignment:auto align, name:"A", address:1, font size:10.0}
*)

end tell
```

Using the above, you're able to see specific characteristics able to be set. Then you could mimic those settings in your own table as demonstrated below with a slight mix of variations of using the `tell newTable` block

```
tell application "Numbers"
activate
set thisDocument to make new document
tell sheet 1 of thisDocument
    delete every table
    set newTable to make new table with properties ¬
        {name:"Sample Table", position:{16, 43}, column count:5, row count:10, header column count:1, header row count:1, footer row count:1}
    tell newTable
        set properties of column 1 to {width:216, background color:{27817, 27821, 27814}}
        set format of column 2 to checkbox
        set properties of column 3 to {width:98, format:currency}
        set properties of row 1 to {background color:{18205, 30509, 7341}}
        set properties of last row to {background color:{18205, 30509, 7341}}
        set value of last cell to "=SUM(E)"
    end tell
end tell
end tell
```

If you're looking for very specific borders, you could start the document off with using a template that uses the desired border you want, since every table started in that template will be the same default table. However since you're scripting it to begin with, and didn't specifically mention looking on how to change the border, I'm under the impression you're after colors, formats, and formulas rather than borders. So the answer to the question still remains "technically yes" you can programmatically set the style of your table.